# Setting Pandas datatypes to match postgres datatypes for use with SQLAlchemy

Tags: pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sqldatatypes

How do I set the following datatypes in Pandas (2.1.1) for use with DataFrame.to_sql for Postgresql backend:

numeric

varchar(n)

Postgresql array: varchar(n)[]

Here is my dataframe - note the listed Postgresql datatypes:

name - varchar(10)

datetime - timestamptz

data_name - varchar(30

data_content - numeric

data_flag - array(varchar))

```
  name                  datetime          data_name  data_content data_flag
0  entry1     2023-10-12 12:36:00+00:00       abc     54.0  [V0, I3]

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column        Non-Null Count  Dtype              
---  ------        --------------  -----              
 0   name          1 non-null      object             
 1   datetime      1 non-null      datetime64[ns, UTC]
 2   data_name     1 non-null      object             
 3   data_content  1 non-null      float64            
 4   data_flag     1 non-null      object             
dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](1), float64(1), object(3)
```

This is what I tried to do as an astype dictionary:

```
type_dict={'name':sq.types.VARCHAR(10),'datetime':sq.types.TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),'data_name':sq.types.VARCHAR(3),'data_content':sq.types.NUMERIC,'data_flag':sq.types.ARRAY(sq.types.VARCHAR())}
test_df=test_df.astype(type_dict)

test_df=test_df.astype(type_dict)
```

This was the result:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpret 'VARCHAR(length=10)' as a data type
```

Comment: What you seem to be describing is normally handled by using the `dtype=` argument to `.to_sql()`, e.g., `test_df.to_sql(table_name, engine, dtype=type_dict, …)`

Comment: hi Gord, thanks for the reply. Yes, using a type dictionary is exactly what I will need to do.  I just don't know what to put IN that dictionary.  What types does pandas, sqlalchemy and postgres all use for varchar, numeric, and postgres arrays?  Note above, when I try to define such a dictionary, i get interpret errors.

Comment: From what I can see you may not need `dtype=` at all; [this code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1986ffc4ded0465aa6613d2dd5e0e9f1) works fine for me. Are you trying to use `if_exists="replace"` ?

Comment: Yes I am, and I have observed that doing so changes the postgres datatypes.  varchar turns to text, numeric turns to float8 and the array is gone entirely, leaving just a text column.

Comment: I just tried your `type_dict` and it worked fine for me when I used it in `.to_sql()`. See the updated [gist](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/1986ffc4ded0465aa6613d2dd5e0e9f1). Note that it **does not** use `.astype()` to try and mess with the types in the DataFrame; it simply passes `dtype=type_dict` to `.to_sql()` so it can create columns of the desired types.

Comment: It worked!  Thanks!  I was trying to make Pandas use those datatypes, go figure that I never needed to!

Answer (score 0):

The `type_dict` was fine …

```py
type_dict = {
    'name': sq.types.VARCHAR(10),
    'datetime': sq.types.TIMESTAMP(timezone=True),
    'data_name': sq.types.VARCHAR(3),
    'data_content': sq.types.NUMERIC,
    'data_flag': sq.types.ARRAY(sq.types.VARCHAR())
}
```

… it was just being used in the wrong place. `.astype()` uses a dict containing numpy, pandas, or Python types to modify the data types in the DataFrame itself, so that `type_dict` did not work. However, `.to_sql()` uses SQLAlchemy types to control the data types of the columns in the database table, so it worked fine

```py
engine.echo = True
test_df.to_sql(
    "other_table", engine, if_exists="replace", index=False, dtype=type_dict
)
"""
CREATE TABLE other_table (
    name VARCHAR(10), 
    datetime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, 
    data_name VARCHAR(3), 
    data_content NUMERIC, 
    data_flag VARCHAR[]
)
"""
```